# Bigcommerce Stencil Page ID?

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

In Bigcommerce's Stencil object model docs : [here is the link](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/global-resources#Pages)

I am not seeing any reference to a basic page's id. Though I can see the "**pageID**"  [shown when hovering over the page name in the admin interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo2ss.jpg)

Is this pageID value accessible through Handlebars at all?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by a basic page? Like a content web page?

Comment: @Alyss - yes I believe he is referring to the id of a content web page. I just noticed that on a content page of a stencil theme, the pageid appears in the last item of the breadcrumbs list. It would be helpful to have this pageid also appear in the "page" object as well as for each page in the list of "pages".

Comment: @Alyss Yes, I am trying to loop though all pages and capture each page's unique pageID. The end use would be to use that pageID in an if statement for conditionally showing specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems it's only possible to get the pageid for the page you are viewing. This probably isn't what you need. You probably want the pageid for every page in the `pages` list. Hopefully they can add that soon. However, just in case it helps you, this is how I'm getting the pageid for the page that is currently being viewed:

```
{{#each breadcrumbs}}
  {{#if @last}}
    {{this.pageid}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm using this method to load a specific stylesheet based on the page. I have a mapping of stylesheets for each page in `config.json`:

```
"settings": {
  "page_stylesheets": {
    "151": {"file_name": "my-custom-stylesheet.css"}
}
```

I added a block in the  of templates/layouts/base.html:

```
{{#block "pageStyles"}} {{/block}}
```

Then, at the top of my templates/pages/page.html file, I have the following:

```
{{#partial "pageStyles"}}
  {{#each breadcrumbs}}
    {{#if @last}}
      {{#with (lookup ../../theme_settings.page_stylesheets this.pageid)}}
        {{{stylesheet (concat 'assets/css/' this.file_name)}}}
      {{/with}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
{{/partial}}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution above, however, that's a nice solution for a different scenario.